# Displaying derivative and result in one line

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter, sympy

I try to write a template for error calculation in jupyter. I am pretty new to Python and markdown. My Problem is i don't know how to display the derivative in symbols and the result in one line.
I can use display(md(f"Lösung der Ableitung:  $${latex(derivative_R124)}={d_R124}$$")) to get this:

[image]

But i want this in one line. I really don't like the long number without 10^-5 and formatting shorter would be great. Something like 3.389*10^-5

[image]

I tried to google it and was looking for a hint, but did not find anything useful.

Comment: You can use sympy's Eq to represent an equation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how would I do that? Do you have an example?

Comment: Finally, found what you meant. Thank you.

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/solvers.html